# select specific time from diffrent dates datetime mysql field

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a range of dates like 
*2015-05-31* 17:36:36.000000 
to 
*2015-12-20* 22:20:00.000000.

well, i want fetch rows which are between 17 and 19 of each day in that period of time. of course it is important that include minutes too.

i mean, in every single day, if a row has a time which is between 17 to 20, i need that.

What query should i use?

i used

```
SELECT * 
FROM (`orktape`) 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') >= '2015-05-31 17:36:36.000000' 
AND STR_TO_DATE(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') < '2015-12-20 22:20:00.000000' 
ORDER BY `timestamp` desc
```

but it result all the rows which are between 2015-05-31 17:36:36.000000 and 2015-12-20 22:20:00.000000 which include some rows like 2015-12-20 02:20:00.000000 which is not the correct result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select in a range of hours by...

```
SELECT * FROM orktape WHERE HOUR(mytimestamp) >= 17 AND HOUR(mytimestamp) < 19
```

Not sure what your timestamp column is called, I would not call it timestamp, that could be confusing.

Comment: And what about the date and minute? ok by adding DATE(timestamp)>LOBLOBLOB the date will be ok. but what about minute?

Comment: The HOUR code above will include all between 17:00:00.000000 and 18:59:59:999999, it is only checking the hour not the minutes as well.

Comment: thanks for answering, but i need minutes too. what i have to do?

Comment: Can you just add MINUTES(mytimestamp) > x as well

Comment: yes thanks it works, i know all but some silly mistakes makes it wrong. no HOUR and no MINUTE was the problem i used them before. Just an "if" was the problem. anyway thanks. :)